# How can I output/print "proof" that the server is being rebooted using the script I've written?

Tags: python, ssh, server, paramiko

Essentially I wrote a script that reboots a server using python and an SSH library called paramiko. My script runs as it should, but I don't know if it is actually rebooting the server because the server is not on site in the office. Is there a way where I can print and output "proof" that the server is actually being rebooted ? I am a little new to using python to give commands to network devices using SSH.

I did actually run my code and it runs as it should, but I have not tested to see if a server is actually turning on and off.

There is no need to copy and paste all of my code, but there are two functions that are extremely important:

```
def connectToSSH(deviceIP, deviceUsername, devicePassword):
    ssh_port = 22
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(deviceIP, ssh_port, deviceUsername, devicePassword)
    time.sleep(5)

    return ssh

def reboot_server(ssh):

    prompt = raw_input('Are you sure you want to reboot this server ?')

    if prompt.lower() == 'y' or prompt.lower() == 'n':
        print('Proceeding to reboot the switch\n')
    else:
        print('Proceeding to exit the program\n')
        sys.exit(-1)

    channel = ssh.invoke_shell()

    ssh.exec_command("/sbin/reboot -f > /dev/null 2>&1 &")  # executes command to reboot server , is this the right command ? I found this on another stackOverflow post ?

    channel.close()

    print("Please wait for server to be rebooted")
```

I am receiving no compile errors but I want to be sure that the command:

```
ssh.exec_command("/sbin/reboot -f > /dev/null 2>&1 &")
```

is actually rebooting the server. If it is, is there a way I can print/output proof that it is being rebooted ? If so, how do I go about doing that ?

Comment: You already have `Proceeding to reboot the switch` printed before the reboot, is that not enough? What is exactly "proof" of the reboot?

Comment: @Norrius I'm a paranoid person and I just want it too output some logging information gibberish. My coworker is off today but I guess I can wait to ask him. The "proof" is for my peace of mind really...

Comment: I've never used python to ping a server, but couldn't you try to ping it immediately after you start the reboot? Maybe ping it multiple times depending on how long it takes to reboot. And just post the ping results.

Comment: Why not have an stdout from the boot command so if `ssh.exec_command("/sbin/reboot -f > /dev/null 2>&1 &")` returns `True` you can `print("Boot successfull")`

Comment: @Jeffyx I added another canPing boolean function to see if it rebooted and it looks like it does ping successfully after it reboots. Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want to run `uptime` after the reboot?

Comment: @DavisHerring Sure, why not ? How would I go about doing that ?